# ReactJS Prevent Navbar from rendering on certain components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a web app. The app has a Home page, About, FAQ & Grow page. The Navbar will render on the pages above.
I do not want it to render on my authentication pages - Login & Register
Here is my Index.js:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <Router>
      <App />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    </Router>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

);
Here is my App.js:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route exact path="/faq" component={FAQs} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How do I render the Nav component on the home page, about and FAQ page and not on my Authentication pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and viable option is to include the `Nav` on each of the components that needs it. i.e. Put it inside `Home, about and faq pages` respectively.

Comment: I guess you're right. Thank you

Comment: @OluwaferanmiAjiboye if you found the answer helpful, please mark it as correct.